# How to draw lines using drawLine()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to draw a line using `drawLine()`. The line is not appearing, can someone debug this code?

```
 fun LinePlacer(btn: Button?, call:Int,cPlayer:Int?){
    var xStart=btn!!.getTop().toFloat()
    var yStart=btn!!.getLeft().toFloat()
    var xStop=xStart+100
    var yStop=yStart+100
    var paint=Paint()

    paint.setColor(Color.RED)
    Draw(xStart,yStart,yStop,xStop,paint)

}
fun Draw(xStart:Float,yStart:Float,yStop:Float,xStop:Float,paint: Paint){
     var canvas=Canvas()
     paint.setColor(Color.RED)
     paint.setStrokeWidth(2f)
     canvas.drawLine(xStart,yStart,xStop,yStop,paint) 
}
```

Edit 1:
This function is called from a main function. I made this to test if how the draw line works. That btn is a button that i press. I need to draw line over that button.
Also some variables are not used now.. but i need them later...

Edit 2: i have been trying but i am not getting anywhere.

Question 1: Do i need to add something in my main xml file to use the canvas?

Question 2: i have overrided the onDraw. But how to call it from main function when i need?

Question 3: i have seen using invalidate() to draw shapes. How to use that...

Comment: what is this: btn!! ??

Comment: Sry i didnt specify it

Comment: You can't just draw whenever you want. You must use the `Canvas` provided by `onDraw()`, only within the `onDraw()` callback. You can use `invalidate()` to request that it be called for the next frame. https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: Can you modify my code like you said? I am trying but i always get stuck somewhere

Comment: Go to the page I linked and click "Download the sample".

Comment: I am trying had as i can. But i am not getting in